# Get Error In New App Version: No Such Table

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I read a lot of related posts, but I didn't get the solution.

I use the ActiveAndroid library for the database and released my program, but I having trouble in updating the new version.

In the new version of the application, a table is added to the database. Therefore, the database must be updated.
(I made the changes and increased  the database version ).

manifest file:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
        android:value="KashanTakhfifi" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
        android:value="2" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_MODELS"
        android:value="DBTableModel.TableNotificationModel, DBTableModel.TableGuideModel" />
```

But when the new app is install or update,The program will be crash.
because happen error: no such table(which means the database is not updated).

I read in the other posts : the app should be removed and reinstalled.
But I've released the app and this problem is not logical for users.
If I want to delete this library, I will have to make a lot of changes to my code...
What is the solution for me.

Comment: What database library do you use? There must be some method/class, that is executed if migration needed. There you should add new table to database.

Comment: I have used the ActiveAndroid library. And on the manifest, I introduced the new table with the rest, but I do not know what change for migration

Comment: as described [here](https://github.com/pardom-zz/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Schema-migrations) you need file **VERSION_NUMBER.sql** where you makes DB change

Comment: I have meta tag of db_version in manifest.